# jQuery "or" operator not working on mouseleave?

Tags: javascript, jquery

`$('.submenu' || '#categorymenu_100000')` only seems to work on `.submenu`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li a').on("mouseenter", function () {
        if ($(this).attr('href') == "/Pages/Men") {
            $('#categorymenu_100000 .submenu').show();
        }
    });
    $('.submenu' || '#categorymenu_100000').on("mouseleave", function () {
        $('.submenu').hide();
    });
```

Comment: There is no jQuery "or" operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'.submenu' || '#categorymenu_100000'` is a JavaScript expression that results in `'.submenu'`, because `'.submenu'` is a truthy value – it’s a string and it isn’t empty. `||` picks the first truthy value of its operands.

If you want to select elements that match either of those selectors, you’ll need to use the CSS separator for that: `,`. jQuery works on CSS selectors and not JavaScript expressions (it is not magic).

```
$('.submenu, #categorymenu_100000').on('mouseleave', …);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want event handlers on both objects, then you should use this:

```
$('.submenu, #categorymenu_100000').on(...)
```

The comma separates multiple selectors in a CSS selector string.

---

Your OR operator is not doing what you think.  This:

```
$('.submenu' || '#categorymenu_100000').on(...)
```

is the same as this:

```
$('.submenu').on(...)
```

because a `string || anotherstring` is always going to return the first truthy value it encounters which is the first string in your expression.  In other words:

```
'.submenu' || '#categorymenu_100000' === '.submenu'
```

Comment: @user2225593 - does this answer your question?